# How can I use the current org-mode buffer as a Target in an org-capture template?

Tags: org-capture

I want to design an org-capture definition that targets the current org file.  Looking at the list of available targets it's not clear to me what I should use.  Considering using (current-buffer) as the file name in the Target definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(file buffer-name)` will set the target to the current buffer. Here's an example capture template:

```lisp
("T" "test" plain (file buffer-name) "\n- %?")
```

Explanation: The doc string for `org-capture-templates` says:

> ...
> Most target specifications contain a file name.  If that file
> name is the empty string, it defaults to ‘org-default-notes-file’.            A file can also be given as a variable **or as a function called
> with no argument**.

Emphasis added.

In this case, the function is `buffer-name`, which gives the file name associated with the current buffer (when called with no argument).

Comment: Added an explanation to answer @Matt's question (which was incorrectly submitted as an answer).